# LOAD DATA LOCAL, How do I skip the first line?

Tags: sql, mysql, csv, import, load-data-infile

I'm trying to Load a CSV file into my MySQL database,
But I would like to skip the first line.

I fact It contains the name of my columns and no interesting data.

Here is the query I'm using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/myfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE tableName
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(column,column,column);
```

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

([reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html))

Comment: I have a question. Lets take IGNORE LINES 5; as an example. Would that ignore line 5 or lines 1-5?

Comment: @EatSleepCode, it will ignore the first N lines, so lines 1 to 5, this last included.

Answer (score 46):

For those curious, IGNORE N LINES should be after the separator qualifiers:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/myfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE tableName
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(column,column,column);
```

Comment: Your note on the placement of IGNORE is KEY!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
IGNORE N LINES
LOAD DATA INFILE "/path/to/file.csv"
INTO TABLE MYTABLE 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```